# i want when new user signup i receive a mail of new signup but its not working

Tags: php, mysql, email, post, mysqli

without mail function insert query work properly but with mail function it will that page is not working page is unable to handle this request. Giving an HTTP ERROR 500 it send us an email on every new signup.

```
<?php
require_once 'sessions.php';;

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "medmocksroot";
$password = "medmocks123";
$dbname = "medmocks";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (Name,Contact,email,Password)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Request Submitted Successfully";
} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
/*header("Location: signup.php");*/

if (isset($_REQUEST['signup_mail']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "medmocks7@gmail.com";
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $subject = "New Signup";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
  $pass = $_REQUEST['password'];


  //send email

$sql = mail("medmocks7@gmail.com",  "Subject:" .$subject, "From:" .$email, "Name:" .$name, "Contact:" .$contact, "Password:" .$pass);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

  header("Location:signup.php");

  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("Message Sent Successfully")';  //not showing an alert box.
  echo '</script>';
  exit;

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL Injection. Please use prepared statements to prevent this. Regarding the 500 error, Why are you using the mail function to create a SQL statement? What does it do? Is the email being sent even with the 500 error?

Comment: Also if you redirect before you output an alert, it won't be shown

Comment: This code is a trainwreck. Besides the above issues, `$sql` is the result of a call to `mail()` which returns a boolean, not a sql query. I don't know how that could ever be considered to work.